# Rethinkdb Query Not Working

Tags: python, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python, reql

I'm doing the following query on Rethinkdb:

```
r.table('skydata').filter(r.row("DeviceID").eq("JBAnFrdlbkcO").and(r.row("TS").ge(0)).and(r.row("TS").le(143556949)) ).orderBy("TS")
```

It worked perfect when run directly on Data Explorer on their website and returned me results. When I make the same query in my Python program, however, I got nothing. The query I wrote is:

```
records = rdb.table('skydata').filter( (rdb.row['DeviceID'] == 'JBAnFrdlbkcO') & (rdb.row['TS'] >= '0') & (rdb.row['TS'] <= '143556949') ).order_by('TS').run(conn)
```

Here `records` returned is empty. I think these two are equivalent. I also tried to send JS commands to the server directly:

```
records = rdb.js("r.table('skydata').filter(r.row('DeviceID').eq(%s).and(r.row('TS').ge(%s)).and(r.row('TS').le(%s)) ).orderBy('TS')" % (deviceid, time_start, time_end) ).run(conn)
```

But it says: `r is not defined` I really have no idea why it is like this. I would really appreciate it if someone could help. Thanks.

Comment: In your second query, is the zero supposed to be quoted? The numbers should probably be numeric literals unless those fields actually contain stringified numbers

Comment: @deontologician Thanks a lot! They should be %d rather than strings... It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as mentioned in the discussions, the numbers in the query should not be quoted, unless they are strings. Unquote the numbers should make it work.